# Adding code to a storyboard's UIImageview

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to get an image from an URL and display it within a `UIImageview`.
However, I can't connect my code to my image because I don't know how to.
Previously I just made a nib file and do the coding there, but since I transfered my App to iOS 6 and would like to use a `storyboard` I don't know how to achieve the same thing:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString * imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://app-content.app.com/api_ios/images/%@.png",
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"setup"]];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString: imageURL];
    NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
}
```

As you can see, I'm loading an image from a website and change a string from the URL with the string from the `NSUserdefaults`.
I would like to link `imageview` to the image in my `storyboard` but it won't let me, nor can I use an identifier on the `UIimageview`.
What is the right way to do this with a `storyboard`?

Comment: Do you know how to connect an IBOutlet? You need to create a reference to you ImageView in your viewController, this way you can change the contents of the UIImageView from te code.

Comment: in storyboard you need to define the controller that will handle the nib

Comment: @pedros I know how to create a IBOutley, only with an image I can't add code below it so it won't update itself and since I can't use an identifier either I don't know how to update the image.

Comment: @yunas I would like to move away from NIBs and only use the storyboard.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pedros was right, the IBoutlet was not connected the right way.
It is working now.